# ExtJS Tree from interconnected flat data

Tags: extjs

I've tried for a bit now to hook up a tree in ExtJS to a series of interconnected Stores without any luck. It seams like a thing that should be so easy, but the documentation is not really talking about things like this at all it seams.

So the situation is this: I've got three layers of stores, store 1 contains root level items, store 2 contains all the children associated with the data in store 1 and each entry knows the id of its parent. Same goes for the third layer which references the second layer.

What is the strategy for hooking this up? Can I get the tree to walk the references from store to store to get the appropriate data?

Also restructuring the data into nested JSON as all the examples use is not an option since the API is already given.

I'm new to ExtJS but i know MVC and JS in general so please be spesific when explaining the ExtJS stuff :)

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: This is not how trees work. Use **one** treestore instead of multiple stores.

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation and that is indeed how they are used, but as I said, I don't control how the data is structured, so I will need to get the TreeStore to fetch from the other stores somehow. I.e., I want some way to tell the TreeStore to look up what it needs from the other stores, or something along those lines.